# How can i use mvc default user Id in my class Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC. I want to implement an app like facebook. 
I write 3 Model for this. here is my model.

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment>Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

In the User id property i want to use MVC account Id. 
I want to inject default authenticate Id to my User Id property.
After this I use Code first approach to get auto generated code. 
How can i do this. plz help me to do this. :) 
Have any error in my code? i am confuse. Suggestion need.

Comment: which MVC version you are using?

Comment: I use visualStudio2013 and MVC5

Comment: Ok, MVC5 uses new way of authenticating users, there is a class called ApplicationUser, which inherits from IdentityUser, you can customize this class "ApplicationUser" to whatever you need. I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server for your database, right? if yes I'll provide a some example code.

Comment: Yes I use Sql Server 2012, Plz give me some example code. I want to use "public string Id { get; set; }" this property by application user :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, I guess you need to change part of your DB generating mechanism, I do suggest the following steps:

**DB**

Create your SQL Database (keep it empty for now)

**Code**

- Using VS 2013, Start new Web/ASP.NET Web Application
- Select MVC as a template (default)
- Select Individual User Accounts as authentication (default)
- Go to Server Explorer and Add new Connection (to the database that you have created)
- Copy the Connection String of this new database and replace the connectionstring of the
  DefaultConnection in the Web.Config

Now you are pointing to the new empty database, start the Web Application, do a single registration by entering your email and password, click Register.

**DB**

Go and check the database you will find that around 5 new tables created for you on the Database which will represent the authentication/authorization information.

Continue working on the DB, create your other tables (Post and Comment) and connect them both to the AspNetUsers (which will represent your registered users)

**Code**

Go back to the code:

- Right click on Models
- Click Add / New Item
- Select ADO.NET Entity Model
- Select Generate From Database
- Select the connection that you have already created in the previous steps
- Click next and select the tables that matters you (Post, Comment)
- Click Finish

By completing this step you have connected the Post and Comment to the MVC default authenticated user.

Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thank u very much sir. I did it. it is working successfully. But I want it code first approach.